# How can I set a string as a Null in swift, when server is returning null value?

Tags: ios, swift

```
let debitCardNum = responseObject!["card_number"] as! String
```

This is my code and I am getting this **error**

> Could not cast value of type 'NSNull' (0x384db1b4) to 'NSString'
>   (0x384e073c).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `let` do like

```
if let Value = responseObject!["card_number"] as? String {
     debitCardNum = Value
}
else
{
    //error
}
```

Comment: @Rahulsingh -- happy to hear , if swift in starting time everyone face the same issue , on that time use `if let` concept , it easy to resolve your issue at the same time day by day u automatically learn yourself, any way happy, if my answer is useful give the tick mark , it is useful for future

Comment: i believe you meant `if let`

Answer (score 1):

This is a good candidate for optionals.

```
 let debitCardNum = responseObject["card_number"] as? String
```

Later on when you want to do something use an `if let` to ensure the variable has a value

```
 if let debitCardNum = debitCardNum {
    // do something
 }
```